# Golang template in Ansible

Tags: docker, logging, ansible

I'm passing as `log_options` the following dict in the Ansible package `docker_container`:

```
log_options:
    tag: "{% raw %}{{.ImageName}}/{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}{% endraw %}"
```

I've already tried with the above trick but it doesn't work the tag is not created in the container. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape every double curly brackets separately, not whole expression:

```
tag: "{{ '{{' }}.ImageName{{ '}}' }}/{{ '{{' }}.Name{{ '}}' }}/{{ '{{' }}.ID{{ '}}' }}"
```